# Is dll file is CIL(common intermidiate language) if not how the CLR execute the CIL?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, cil

In visual studio when we compile the source code it will generate a byte code then when we build it,create a dll file.I have stuck how the byte code(common intermidiate clanguage) is getting execute by the .net framwork.My understand both CIL and DLL are equal but iam not sure about it.please clarify me boss.

Comment: Please try to rephrase / clarify the question.. Improving the language / grammar will help better understand exactly what you are asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "My understand both are equal", which two entities are you referencing to, in that statement?

Answer (score 9):

In short, when a .Net language compiler compiles a project, it is turned into either a *.Net module*, or an *assembly*. Either of them contain *IL (Intermediate Language)* code. A .Net module alone is not usable, as it must be included in an assembly. (.Net modules are not commonly used. Most commonly, the dll you get from compiling a project is a **one module assembly**).

Once you "install" this assembly on a target machine, you have two options:

- It can either be installed as is, i.e. the Dll contains IL. Only during execution, a component of *.Net runtime*, called *Jitter* will convert it to machine code (*native assembly*), as the code is executed. The process of converting IL to native machine code is repeated each time the assembly is loaded for execution, for each new process.
- It can be converted to machine code during installation, (using tools like *ngen*). With each execution, machine code is ready to be executed, and hence would provide faster startup / first time execution of methods.

**Note**: The topic in general is broad, and this is 10,000 ft level overview of the process. There are many details, and up-coming technologies like *.Net Native* have been left out, to keep this answer simple and most relevant to the way the question has been posed.

Answer (score 2):

In simple words,

C# -> C# compiler (compile time) -> Assembly (DLL/EXE) or .net Module (MSIL form)

Assembly -> JIT compiler (run time) -> machine code (binary form)

For more details,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ht8ecch6(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I think that simply saying "assembly" is very confusing here, because that word has two different meanings, both of which could be relevant here: [assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) vs. [assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_%28CLI%29).

Answer (score 1):

The Common Intermediate Language (CIL) code in the .NET framework is the .DLL and .EXE files that you get once Source Code is compiled by the compiler.

The compilation process, in simple terms, have roughly 3 main code stages:

1. Source Code (Main input to the compiler)
2. Assembly code/Byte Code (Intermediate result)
3. Machine Code/Native Code (Final Output that undergoes actual execution)

.DLL or .EXE files fall under 2nd stage.

.DLL is known as library assemblies and .EXE is known as process assemblies. Both are in CIL form.

A process assembly represents a process that will use classes defined in library assemblies.

This means that CIL and DLL are not exactly "equal" as CIL comes in two forms - .DLL (static/library assembly) and .EXE(executable/process assembly).

So, in reality, the .DLL file or the .EXE files (CIL form) are usually ported to a client computer that has the .NET framework installed (indicating that the CLR which has the JIT Compiler in it, is present on it) where, on the surface level, it seems that once you click the .EXE file, it gets executed, but in reality, the CLR(JIT) converts the .DLL/.EXE once this file is clicked, to machine code which finally gets executed in the backend.

For more details, check:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_%28CLI%29